# Get Previous item in a list

Tags: c#, sitecore

I've a previous/next setup in the works, and the next functionality is working fine (although, that was created by someone else a while back). As for the previous button, that is giving me a few problems.

Here is the code so far:

```
    private Item getPrevious()
    {
        Item CurrentItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
        var blogHomeID = "{751B0E3D-26C2-489A-8B8C-8D40E086A970}";
        Item BlogItem =db.Items.GetItem(blogHomeID);
        Item[] EntryList= BlogItem.Axes.SelectItems("descendant::*[@@templatename='BlogEntry']");

        Item prevEntry = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < EntryList.Length; i++)
        {
            if (EntryList[i] == CurrentItem)
            {
                return prevEntry;
            }

            prevEntry = EntryList[i];
        }
    }
```

I get that you need to subtract 1 from the current item in the list to get the previous, but so far, all this seems to do is display the exact same entry for the previous button. It's always the latest entry in the list, not the previous one. I feel like this shouldn't be so difficult but it could be the old code I'm trying to work with. Not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `GetPreviousSibling()` and `GetNextSibling()` methods:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.GetPreviousSibling()

Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.GetNextSibling()
```

These will return the previous and next sibling, or null if the current item is the first/last respectively.

If you want to restrict by template type then you can use the `preceding` and `following` xpath queries:

```
Item previous = Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.SelectItems("./preceding::*[@@templateid='{template-guid}']").LastOrDefault();

Item next = Sitecore.Context.Item.Axes.SelectSingleItem("./following::*[@@templateid='{template-guid}']");
```

Note the use of `SelectItems` and `LastOrDefault()` on the first query. Both queries give you a list of Items sorted by order.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a condtion to stop the search in the list , so you always return the last item in the list .

```
Item  prevEntry  = null;
for (int i = 0; i < EntryList.Length; i++)
{          
     if (EntryList[i] == CurrentItem)   
     {
         return prevEntry;
     }         

     prevEntry  = EntryList[i];
}
```

Comment: It didn't seem to change anything. It makes sens to stop the list at a specific point, but I tried this code and it didn't change the results. Should there be EntryList[i-1] at some point?

Comment: that might mean that the EntryList does not contain CurrentItem

Comment: I updated my code so that all entries are retrieved for the EntryList loop, including the current one. However, no change in the results.

Comment: you might want to comapre values  and not refrences . I would change  the == operator , into Equals , and overide the Equals  method in the Item class